# C# User interface

Tags: c#, user-interface

I have been programming in java for a couple of years now. Not long ago i decided that it was time to make a change and learn C#.

Now since it both visual studio and C# is new to me i have decided that since i have to learn it anyway i might learn the newest tools there is.

However i am unable to find out what GUI liberay to use.  my first search indicated that WPF is the newest "lib" for creating microsoft UI many other threads gave an indication of that this might not be the case.

Therefore i am asking you guys what is the newest UI "lib" for C# and what would you advice me to use?

Comment: WPF would be a good one to learn. Maybe get a base of windows forms knowledge first.

Comment: WPF should be a no-brainer, at least if you're aiming for *current tachnology*. If you start with WinForms you'll have to pretty much un-learn everything you got out of WinForms to properly use WPF, so skip the legacy crap and go WPF :)

Comment: @retailcoder +1 just for "legacy crap". I couldn't have said it better myself...

Comment: @HighCore I knew you'd upvote this post!

Answer (score 1):

There are two main flavors of GUI (not counting web): WPF and Windows Forms. WPF is much more recent and if you have no experience on Windows Forms, WPF may be recommended GUI alternative.

Now WPF may have several "flavours" - it is kind of different in abilities in desktop applications, silverlight applications and windows store applications, desktop applications having most of the features, other two has limited set, mostly because of performance and security reasons (for example you can't render UI to image in windows store applications, but in desktop applications you can).

WPF has better hardware acceleration support, has better binding and async/threading support, is much more flexible, many elements look may be changed very easily - which can't be done so easy in Windows Forms, like combo box - you can change color in Windows Forms very easily, but if you will need rounded edges, that will be hard one.
Also WPF can be used in MVVM pattern easily, which is quite a challenge in Windows Forms.

Windows Forms on the other hand is little bit easier to learn + plus it has very good third party components - like Telerik, Devexpress. Both vendors have components for WPF also, but they ain't as good as Windows Forms ones, mostly because they were designed using Windows Forms knowledge, which doesn't fit WPF.

Comment: Thank you for you response is it possible that you can post some tutorials i can take on WPF? That is if you know any

Comment: I don't have anything particular, but I would search for WPF + Blend tutorials/videos, as Blend is important part of WPF development in my opinion.

Comment: WPF data binding isn't just *better than in WinForms* - it's totally *centric* to the way you should be thinking about UI design.

Comment: @giedrius I disagree winforms is "easier to learn". That's only true if you have been exposed to winforms BEFORE learning WPF. MVVM is much simpler and beautiful than the many horrible code-behind type of hacks required to do anything useful in winforms (not to mention the absurd amount of P/Invoke and "owner draw" required to customize anything)

Comment: @giedrius Plus I also disagree that 3rd party winforms components are somehow better than the WPF components from these same 3rd parties. We use DevEx WPF and it's awesome. The only difference is that winforms is completely useless and horrible without DevEx or Infragistics, whereas you can get a decent UI in WPF withou any of them.

Comment: @HighCore - regarding third party compoments I use my self Devexpress and not only my opnion about their WPF components is like I wrote in answer: http://lukhezo.com/2011/03/15/should-i-use-devexpress-wpf-controls-for-a-new-project/

Comment: @HighCore - if you would search, I think you would find that many agree, that WPF has a steep learning curve, simply because it is much more powerful and customizable. WPF came after Windows Forms, so it is natural, that Microsoft learned something from their experience and fixed things. But that is only my subjective opinion, as I've learned Windows Forms way before WPF was created.

Comment: @giedrius WPF has a steep learning curve, no doubt. Still, many struggle with WPF just because they bring the winforms baggage. and WPF does not play well with the kind of horrible hacks winforms developers are used to (such as manipulating the whole UI in procedural code, or doing `OnRender()` type of stuff). It has been much happier to me because I never touched winforms, I went directly to WPF, and it just feels much more natural and mature, whereas winforms code-behind type of stuff just feels noob and crappy.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Giedrius, either Windows Forms or WPF.

Personally, i would start with Forms for a few weeks, get to know the environment, then move on to WPF and the lovely world of XAML.

Answer (score 1):

WPF is the right technology if you are targeting users with good machines. It leverage the power of graphics card and supports vector graphics. You will get good development speed with the XAML system and much more

If you are looking for any third party controls you can evaluate Infrajistics or Telerik.But depends on your UI requirements.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of newest technologies then WPF is certainly the one I'd recommend you learn, but there is quite a level of interoperability between WPF and WinForms, i.e. you can host WinForm controls in WPF and (I think) vice versa.

One thing to be aware of is that WPF is a completely different beast to winforms - you can still do the usual drag and drop, but for fancy stuff you need to be changing the XAML and that can take some getting your head around.

Edit - it's worth taking the effort to learn WPF though because once you have then you'll be producing rich interfaces with ease.

Answer (score 1):

For anything prior to Windows 8 then the latest is **WPF**. As of Windows 8 you have Metro (name changed I know) but then you could still use your newly aquired XAML skills (picked up from WPF) or start getting into HTML 5 and CSS 3 which would also stand you in good stead for web-based applications.

Win Forms is older than WPF but still well loved / established and can be useful in places. Like most things, choose the right tool for the job.

Comment: can you name 1 single area where anybody would choose dinosaur winforms instead of beautiful, scalable, vector based, XAML based WPF?

Comment: @HighCore - Ha, ha... I wish it could be WPF all the way! As I say, all depends on what you are doing. For one if you are working in a company with a large suite of third-party Win Forms controls (like Telerik, Infragistics) but not comparable WPF versions (I have worked for such companies, shudder). Another real world example, becoming rarer though thankfully, is running on older technology such as Windows 2000 (again, I have had to support that) then Win Forms will be the only choice. In an ideal world you would go WPF all the way, but life is rarely that kind! :-)

Comment: @HighCore - WinForms is quite common in corporate type programming jobs. There's a lot of legacy code, legacy controls and legacy senior programmers who require it be used. The same is true of things like Entity Framework, LINQ, MVC, etc...

Comment: @jfrankcarr there's also a lot of COBOL around (mostly in banks, that I know of)... that doesn't mean someone who is willing to learn stuff in 2013 is going to go COBOL.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to learn html, css and js. As I know you can build Microsoft Windows 8 .net applications using these languages. Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211385.aspx) and also it would be useful if you'll decide to make web application, where all these languages are using also.

If you don't want to limit your self with Windows 8, than try WPF. Applications on WPF will be able to run on any machine with .net framework version you used for application.

GL

Comment: -1. HTML doesn't hold a candle to XAML.

Comment: +1 The questioner asked what the newest "lib" was, and HTML/CSS/js fits that description, then also what we'd advise. I thought this answer fitted the question. And HTML/CSS/js are probably the technologies of the future...

Comment: @ChrisSpicer when you can `<TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}"/>` in HTML then you can say it's a useful thing. until then, it doesn't hold a candle. period. and btw, javascript? are you kidding?

Comment: JavaScript can be painful but using something like Knockout.js means you can have nice data-binding with ease!

Comment: This is going slightly off topic, but with Javascript you can create whizzy web pages, build phone apps with PhoneGap, I could even create an App for my Samsung TV with it. It's becoming pervasive.

Comment: @chrisspicer you can also build an app and make it run in my [nokia 1100](http://cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/no1100.gif) cellphone with java... that doesn't change the fact it's a shitty dinosaur language and framework that hasn't evolved since the 90s.

Comment: +1 for balance; the answer does fit the question, even if it doesn't match HighCore's MVVM-based religion.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, WPF is the way to go.

One thing that has not been mentioned is that, (since you have java experience) you can think of WPF versus other technologies (such as winforms) the same way you can think of JavaFX versus previous java UI technologies (such as Swing).

Actually, JavaFX seems like a really poor copy of WPF. the language used to define the UI is XML-based (like XAML is), it has (much poorer) support for DataBinding, and many other similarities.